# std::unordered_set constructors

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I've been looking at the constructors of unordered_set. Is it not possible to construct an unordered_set with a custom allocator instance WITHOUT setting the number of hash buckets? I'd really rather not mess with implementation details because I want a custom allocator, and the type provides no definitions for the default value. MSDN only gives like three overloads for the constructor, none of which are terribly useful.

Edit: Holy crap. My STL implementation of std::hash won't specialize for strings with a custom allocator type- it can only do the explicit typedefs std::string and std::wstring. I mean, I can understand not wanting to try to hash random character strings, but just because it's got a custom allocator? This disgusts me.

```
tokens(std::unordered_set<string>().bucket_count(), std::hash<string>(), std::equal_to<string>(), stl_wrapper::hash_set<string>::allocator_type(this))
template<typename Char, typename CharTraits, typename Allocator> class std::hash<std::basic_string<Char, CharTraits, Allocator>>
    : public std::unary_function<std::basic_string<Char, CharTraits, Allocator>, std::size_t> {
public:
    size_t operator()(const std::basic_string<Char, CharTraits, Allocator>& ref) const {
        return std::hash<std::basic_string<Char, CharTraits>>()(std::basic_string<Char, CharTraits>(ref.begin(), ref.end()));
    }
};
```

Solves the problems, but redundant constructions and copying? Ewwwww.

Comment: Regarding your edit: yup, afraid so. `std::hash` is a bit lacking, in particular I think the standard should provide a function to hash a sequence of bytes, to make it easier to specialize for UDTs (including your string with custom allocator). But since your alternately-allocated string isn't related to any of the mandated `hash` specializations, you're SOOL with no help in sight. AFAIK you just have to choose your own hash algorithm, then either write a specialization, or specify the hash to your container.

Comment: @Steve: Not quite. The basic_string constructors can take any iterator, so it actually wasn't terribly difficult to extend it to be allocator-agnostic, but it involves a redundant copy, which makes me RAEG.

Comment: @DeadMG: yeah, depending why you're using a custom allocator. If you want *all* allocation in your program to go through your allocator, then it's not just a redundant copy, it's total fail.

Comment: @DeadMG: actually, I may just not have done my homework. There's `std::collate<charT>::hash`, so possibly you can do `namespace std { template <> struct hash<basic_string<char,char_traits<char>,MyAlloc>> { typedef size_t result_type; typedef basic_string<char,char_traits<char>,MyAlloc> argument_type; result_type operator()(const argument_type &str) { return collate<char>::hash(str.begin(), str.end()); }};}`. Which is a bit verbose just to pass on a call...

Comment: @Steve: What makes you say that? Right now, all unmanaged allocations from each owning object go through there, but a global allocation hook can't know the owning object.

Comment: @DeadMG: I say it's total fail, because if you did want all string allocation to go through your allocator, then the redundant copy to a `string` will allocate from `std::allocator<char>` instead.

Comment: @Steve: That's entirely true- but it's an rvalue and the memory will be freed right away, so when the hash method returns, the total memory in use hasn't changed and thus I don't care. Let's just hope that my favourite compiler's optimizer can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's strange, but you are right.  I suppose the thought was that it's overkill to support all possible parameter combinations, with defaults.

The best way I can think to handle this is to construct an empty `unordered_set` with all default settings, get the default bucket count from it using `unordered_set::bucket_count`, and then use that as input when you instantiate the container you actually want.

```
unordered_set<int> temp;
size_t buckets = temp.bucket_count;
unordered_set<string> actual(buckets, Hash(), Pred(), 
    YourAllocator(param1 /*, etc */));
```

Comment: I can't do that if my custom allocator can't be default constructed.

Comment: @Steve: Because YourAllocator() is a compile error, as there is no default constructor.

Comment: Right but the point is that you pass in the allocator you want on that second call, with other parameters set to their defaults.  Sorry for being dense, I must be missing something.  Can't you just sub in the `YourAllocator` constructor you want as param 4?

Comment: @Steve: Sorry, I mis-stated what I meant. You can't default-construct the original, temporary variable, because it tries to default-construct the allocator, which it can't do.

Comment: @DeadMG - yes but the point of the first call is only to determine the implementation's default bucket count.  The container is then discarded.  Default allocator there is fine.

Comment: @Steve: You're absolutely right. I hadn't considered constructing an unordered_set of different type. Now I just need to convince my hash implementation that it hashes the same regardless of how I chose to allocate said string.

Comment: Hope it works out, good luck.  Still a pain to have to do this to get the default bucket count, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing the `Allocator`, it makes sense to control the number of buckets too, after all both are memory related :)

Steve gave the heart of the method if you don't want to, now let me propose a helper function :)

```
template <typename T>
size_t number_buckets()
{
  std::unordered_set<T> useless;
  return useless.bucket_count();
}
```

And with that, a little (simple) helper:

```
template <typename T, typename Hash, typename Pred, typename Allocator>
std::unordered_set<T,Hash,Pred,Allocator>
  make_unordered_set(Hash const& hash, Pred const& pred, Allocator const& alloc)
{
  static size_t const nbBuckets = number_buckets<T>();
  return std::unordered_set<T,Hash,Pred,Allocator>(nbBuckets, hash, pred, alloc);
}
```

Works pretty well with `auto`:

```
auto set = make_unordered_set<std::string>(Hash(), Pred(), Allocator(1,2,3));
```

You could also, of course, simply rip the constant out of your favorite implementation.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense to control both, as one controls how much memory is allocated, or not, and the implementation details of the algorithm in question- and the other just measures it. The two are not at all necessarily related.